# How to proceed with splitting question?

Tags: support, asking-questions, editing

Oh my, I hope I'm not wasting anybody's time here.

I posted [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/questions-regarding-kants-perpetual-peace-on-representation-and-permissive-law) quite some time ago, it didn't get any answers and by now I am ready to answer them myself (which I would gladly do). By now I also realise that putting two questions in there wasn't the smartest move, so I would like to split the post in two. I'm only worried about the up-votes, because if I edit the post at hand, the up-votes aren't "fair" any more (maybe I got them for the part I'm deleting). So what do I do? Edit the one at hand and add one new question, or delete the one and open two new ones? Or maybe neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and 'split' the question as you see fit. Probably the most favorable way to execute this would be to reframe/revise the original question to ask a single question, and then ask new additional questions (maybe with some of the content removed from the original.)

This is all encouraged and definitely part of the natural lifecycle of clarifying a concern.

Often there will be a big-picture question followed by several further specifying questions. Just be sure to link back to the 'big' question from the more specific ones to make clear they're connected, and to help readers follow the line of thinking.